# Xamarin.Forms MVVM TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm writing my first Xamarin.Forms MVVM application and I'm writing the view entirely with XAML. I need to be able to detect when the user taps a Xamarin.Forms.Label and to do so I've followed the example in the following Xamarin guide:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/gestures/#Using_ICommand

And my Label's XAML looks like this:

```
<Label Text="Test Check">
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnClickCheckOption}"
                          CommandParameter="TestCheck" />
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

This causes a run-time error when the app starts that states:

"An exception of type Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException' occured in Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.DLL but was not handled in user code. Additional information: BindableProperty CommandProperty not found on TapGestureRecognizer"

The error that there is no CommandProperty or CommandParameterProperty on the Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer class is clearly not true according to the Xamarin API:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer%2f*

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey does Xamarin support tap and hold gesture?

Comment: @Arti you can check this tutorial on [Gestures](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is valid, and should work, provided you run it on one of the latest build of `Xamarin.Forms`, as the `CommandProperty` is brand new.

At the time of this writing, the version you should target is `1.2.2-pre2` (nuget pre-release)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was using Xamarin.Forms v1.0.6186 and the code started working when I upgraded to v1.2.2.